# navigationItem always become nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, null, uinavigationitem

I have IBoutlet for navigationItem and I write as

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItemRoster;
```

Then, I write to set title view.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = @"Select User";
        self.navItemRoster.titleView = [Helpers getCenterTitleViewWithTitle:@"Select User"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But I can't set title view. So, I check and debug. I found out this. It is always nil. How shall I do? What are the possible mistakes?

[image]

Edited: I have also connected in IB.

[image]

Comment: And you're sure you've connected it in IB?

Comment: yes. I have connected also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not opening this VC using this method `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` then you have to write this code in `-(void)viewDidLoad` method to set the title.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Select User";
    self.navItemRoster.titleView = [Helpers getCenterTitleViewWithTitle:@"Select User"];
}
```

Comment: amm...really strange..why it work in viewdidload? Can you explain? I also have other navigation item in other VC and I just declare in initWithNibName. They are okay. But now, why it only work in viewdidload? Thanks for your help. I follow yours and it is okay now.

Comment: @KhantThuLinn I think I have written it in my answer that, it depends on how you opening your VC, if you are opening it using `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` method then your code will work else not. But `-(void)viewDidLoad` will always run everytime tour VC loads.

Comment: yes. I call like this.     RosterVC *vc = [[RosterVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RosterVC" bundle:nil];
So, it goes through initWithNibName.

Comment: @KhantThuLinn Hmm, not sure why it not called, but its always a good idea to write all initialization code in `-(void)viewDidLoad` method.